# Performance difference between Primary Key and Unique Clustered Index in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have 2 tables that have about 40M rows. the size of database is about 20GB, most are for these 2 tables. Everyday, We need delete some data, i.e. about 10M rows. So, we are using batch delete to keep the log file within certain size.

originally, there is no primary key for the table. But has unique, clustered index for each table. the delete takes for ever. i.e. it takes about 2-3 hours to delete 500K rows on a virtual machine. * before delete, the index was rebuilt.

now, we converted the unique, clustered index to primary key. it takes about 20-30 minutes to delete 2M rows.

I understand there is difference between primary key and unique clustered index, but why the performance is so different?

anyone has some insight?

thanks

Comment: Technically there shouldnt be any diff if both are declared as clustered index and on same columns. Did you see any diff in plan generated by these two different approaches?
One ovbvious question but still asking, was the PK on the same columns as the Unique clustered index?
Also, why were you creating the index before delete for unique clustered index? If there is certain kind of pattern in data delete try to have a partitioned table..

Comment: I'm curious if it would be beneficial to insert the set that you want to keep into a new table, then `TRUNCATE` your parent table to save on logging.

Comment: What's the difference in query plans? Also, is the primary index also clustered (which it is by default, unless you specify NONCLUSTERED)?

Comment: Did you try with Non `Clustered Index`? Reason being - the `non clustered index` keeps `Row locator id` info and `Clustered index keeps complete row info. second point is did you check it directly at the machine instead of the `Virtual machine`, because it depends how much `RAM` is being allocated to the `Virtual machine` and `access time` depends upon the `RAM`.

Comment: what kind of where clause are you using for delete statement?or there is no where clause at all?

Comment: I checked the execution plans, both are the same although the cost has a little bit difference.

there is where clause: the batch delete is like:

DELETE TOP (@C) FROM table1 Where EXISTS ( SELECT Table2.MessageId FROM table2 WHERE table2.MessageId = table1.MessageId AND table2.LogDate < DATEADD([month], -3, GETDATE()) )

In the tests, we used the same VM machine. I would think the performance should be similar no matter how slow/fast it is. However, as we can see, the performance is very different.

Answer (score 6):

Rolling my 8-Ball: if you declared a *non-clustered* primary key (as it seems to suggest from your post) then on each batch you would very likely hit the [index tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx). Thus each batch would do a full scan of 40M rows to delete the batch size. Then, on the next batch, again a full scan. And so on until your 10M would be deleted. With a clustered key the batches should scan only the actual rows being deleted (of course I assume your batch delete criteria would actually use the clustered key...). As you see, there are many unknowns when one starts *guessing*...

But ultimately... you have a performance question and you should investigate it using the performance troubleshooting techniques. Capture the execution plans, the [wait stats](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/12/30/an-xevent-a-day-30-of-31-tracking-session-and-statement-level-waits.aspx), the [statistics io](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx). Follow a methodology like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx). Measure. Don't listen to [guesses](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/31/the-bizzaro-guide-to-sql-server-performance/) from someone on the internet that just rolled an [8-Ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_8-Ball)...

Comment: He has mentioned that in his case clustered index was performing very bad but a PK was performing better( and I assume that it was clustered as he did not mention that he declared it as nonclustered index)

Comment: yes, the PK is clustered. the index is unique, clustered. I would think they should not have so much difference in speed. but, it has. I tested in many times. could it because of the data in test?

Comment: were these same plans? Also, when you say perforamnce was not same what did you measure, IO''s,cpu time or elapsed time?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the index prior to delete and then re-add it back after. If I'm not mistaken, the index would be re-organized after each delete; which takes the extra time.

Comment: do you mean PK does not need reorganize? will try removing index to see how the speed it. however, if we reorganize index after delete, I believe the log file size will grow very quickly, which is the original problem we try to deal with.

Comment: PK should be an index as well... I have used this trick (delete/re-add index) in the past and was able to achieve better performance results on insert/delete, so I figured its worth a shot if you are out of options. But this method is a last resort... I think you might be able to get more help if you could post table schema for both of the tables you are working with, the indexes and your query. Do not post them into comments, instead update your post so it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it could be something like your index was very fragmented before one delete operation but not before another.  How fragmented was the clustered unique index?  You could see if there is still a difference in runtime after doing a rebuild on all indexes before the delete with something like `ALTER INDEX ALL ON blah REBUILD`

What options did you use when creating your unique clustered index (specifically what are the following set to: PAD_INDEX, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE, SORT_IN_TEMPDB, IGNORE_DUP_KEY, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS, and ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS)?